# Posting JSON to API Conroller doesn't bind to c# model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I've looked on a number of posts already, but I can't see what I've been doing wrong. I suspect that there is a small issue that I've become blind to. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an API controller which takes HTTPPost, I have a view which is using an AngularJS controller.

The problem I am having is that I can see the request being posted using Fiddler. However the API controller which takes a parameter of Invoice seems to be receiving null. I've checked other posts on here, and although I've found similar issues I haven't been able to find what is wrong in the implementation I have.

Any Ideas? Code below...

The Models are as below;

```
    [Serializable]
public class Invoice
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "invoiceId")]
    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customer")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productDetails")]
    public Product ProductDetails { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "product")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customerID")]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastName")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "town")]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "county")]
    public string County { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "postCode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

The AngularJS controller is as below;

```
// define angular module/app
var formApp = angular.module('invoice', [])
.controller('invoiceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.invoiceDetails = {
    invoiceId: "fbd7fe22-81b1-4886-8d0e-13be442b8444",
    customer: {
        firstName: "Joe",
        lastName: "Bloggs",
        address1: "1 Somewhere",
        address2: "",
        town: "Oxford",
        county: "OXON",
        postCode: "OX26 5TY"
    },
    productDetails: {
        product:"prod name"
    }
}



// process the form
$scope.processForm = function () {

    $http.post(
        '/api/invoice', 
        JSON.stringify($scope.invoiceDetails),
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }


    )
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        if (!data.success) {
            // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
            $scope.errorFirstName = data.errors.firstname;
            $scope.errorLastName = data.errors.lastName;
        } else {
            // if successful, bind success message to message
            $scope.message = data.message;
        }
    });
};
```

});

And the view which posts the details is as below;

```
<div ng-app="invoice" ng-controller="invoiceCtrl">

    <h2 class="content-margin">Create Invoices using this page</h2>

    <h5 class="content-margin">Invoice ID </h5><span ng-model="invoiceDetails.invoiceId"></span>

    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="processForm()">
        <h4>Customer Details</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Forename" class="control-label col-xs-2">Customer Forename:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Forename" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Surname" class="control-label col-xs-2">Customer Surname:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Surname" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="AddressLine1" class="control-label col-xs-2">Address Line 1:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddressLine1" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.address1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="AddressLine2" class="control-label col-xs-2">Address Line 2:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AddressLine2" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.address2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="City" class="control-label col-xs-2">City:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.town">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="County" class="control-label col-xs-2">County:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="County" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.county">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PostCode" class="control-label col-xs-2">Post Code:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PostCode" placeholder="" ng-model="invoiceDetails.customer.postCode">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" />

</form>

</div>
```

**EDIT**

The controller action being called is as below;

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Invoice invoiceDetails)
{
    if (invoiceDetails == null) return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

  //  _invoiceRepository.Add(value);

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { });
}
```

The post is as per below

```
    {
    "invoiceId": "fbd7fe22-81b1-4886-8d0e-13be442b8444",
    "customer": {
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Bloggs",
        "address1": "1 Somewhere",
        "address2": "",
        "town": "Oxford",
        "county": "OXON",
        "postCode": "OX26 5TY"
    },
    "product": {
        "productName": "Prod reg"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to `stringify` your data. `$http.post('/api/invoice', $scope.invoiceDetails)` should suffice. Angular defaults to `application/json` for POST requests too. It may also be worth posting your `ApiController` definition as you may not have named the action correctly or decorated your parameters

Comment: I've added the controller to the question and made the changes you've recommended. It's easier to read, so that's helpful but I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: Try `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Invoice value)`?

Comment: Just tried that it 'value' was still null

Comment: Try renaming the param, `Post(Invoice value)` to `Post(Invoice invoiceDetails)`

Comment: Also, should `product:"prod name"` be `productName:"prod name"` ?

Comment: Do you mean in the JS? if so it's the same as the property name in the model?

Comment: @RGraham Complex types are automatically taken from body, so in this case `FromBody` attribute will not make any difference.

Comment: I would suggest testing your API manually using something like PostMan for Chrome to see if the issue is with the API itself or the client side scripting.

Comment: @OilGray I've tried that already, but was still getting the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `Serializable` attribute on your models. If you remove them everything will work fine. If you need this attribute for some other stuff and can't remove, then you can add `JsonObject` attribute:

```
[JsonObject]
[Serializable]
public class Invoice
{
    // Properties
}
```

Don't forget to do it for all classes that are deserialized from JSON.

Also in last JSON sample that you posted you have `carDetails` instead of `productDetails`. I think it's just a typo.

Comment: I made the change in adding the JsonObject but that returned a HTTP500, I then tried wiht just JsonObject, that seemed to do the same thing. I removed all attributes on the model, but that didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Can you provide error details? Because it works well in my test project. Usually 500 indicates some problem in your code. Can you debug it?

Comment: Ah it worked, seems there was was an issues with an incorrect version of NewtonSoft.Json referenced. the solution worked.